# async in matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I'm trying to make concurrent matrix multiplication in my code. The teacher said to me I have to use async in my do_multiply function, but I don't know how to do it. I think that do_multiply has to start a thread and then has to wait for the result. Here is my do_multiply function:

```
    void do_multiply(matrix_wrap<T> result, matrix_wrap<T> lhs, matrix_wrap<T> rhs) {
              const unsigned height = result.get_height();
              const unsigned width = result.get_width();
              const unsigned span = lhs.get_width();
              assert(span==rhs.get_height());
              for (unsigned i=0; i!=height; ++i)
                 for (unsigned j=0; j!=width; ++j) {
                       result(i, j) = 0;
                       for (unsigned k = 0; k != span; ++k)
                         result(i, j) += lhs(i, k) * rhs(k, j);                   
                  }

               }
```

Where lhs is the first matrix and rhs the second one. 
I think I have to write something like:

```
 auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, add, std::ref(result(i,j)));
 f.get();
```

instead of

```
result(i, j) += lhs(i, k) * rhs(k, j);
```

but I really don't know how and if it works, I only have errors so the code is not builded. Any suggestion?

Comment: You should at least add the errors.

Comment: what should I use instead of async? I'm new in c++, I really don't know what is better for concurrency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiplication of an MxN matrix and an NxP matrix will result in a matrix with size MxP. Note that when multiplying the values, you have to perform separate operations for each component of the matrix. What you should try is launching the computation of each matrix element separately. Since each task is writing to a different memory location, there will be no race conditions do you don't have to worry about synchronization.

Make sure you wait for all the tasks to complete before returning! It should look something like this:

```
void do_multiply(matrix_wrap<T> result, matrix_wrap<T> lhs, matrix_wrap<T> rhs) {
    // here you should probably assert that the result, lhs, and rhs are of compatible
    // sizes. 

    // lambda function that will be launched once for each output matrix element.
    auto compute_element = [&result, &lhs, &rhs](int row, int col)
    {
        T value = T(0);
        ... //compute value here. 
        result(row, col) = value;
    };

    std::vector<std::future<void>> tasks;
    tasks.reserve(result.rows() * result.cols());
    //launch all async tasks. 
    for(int row = 0; row < result.rows(); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < result.cols(); col++)
        {
            auto task = std::async(std::launch::async, compute_element, row, col);
            taks.push_back(move(task));
        }
    }

    //task.get() will only return once the task is finished. 
    for(auto& task: tasks)
    {
        task.get();
    }
    //now all tasks are finished, so we can be sure that all elements
    //of the result matrix are populated. 
}
```

Note that for small matricies (less than hundreds of rows and columns), doing the multiplication this way is most likely slower that just doing it in a single thread.

Comment: mmm ok, this makes sense. Later I will try on my laptop, now I should study better and think again to what I want to do. Thank you Paul!

Comment: Rather than each task doing *exactly one* `(row, column)` pair, you can chunk up multiple pairs. Measure to see what an appropriate chunk size is

Comment: ok I think that my teacher wants something different. In my opinion, he wants that (A+B)*(C+D) where A,B,C,D are matrices is performed in the following way: first (A+B) and (C+D) simultaneously, and then the multiplication. Should I use this code and then add something like wait/sleep or something else in the sum method?

Comment: In that case, you could launch do_add(A, B) as an async task, then perform do_add(C, D). Then, collect the result of the async task and perform the multiply.